# chef-client NTP cookbook error

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, ntp, cookbook

I am trying to run ntp cookbook but getting below error.

Chef Development Kit Version: 1.2.22
chef-client version: 12.5.1

> Recipe: ntp::default
>     * yum_package[ntp] action install

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[ntp]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-bigmem installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm) kernel-enterprise kernel-smp kernel-debug kernel-unsupported kernel-source kernel-devel kernel-PAE kernel-PAE-debug
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: cdc. Please verify its path and try again
---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ntp/recipes/default.rb

 41:     package ntppkg
 42:   end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ntp/recipes/default.rb:41:in `block in from_file'

yum_package("ntp") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "ntp"
  flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name "ntp"
  recipe_name "default"
end
```

> chef-stacktrace.out

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: yum_package[ntp] (ntp::default line 41) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-bigmem installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm) kernel-enterprise kernel-smp kernel-debug kernel-unsupported kernel-source kernel-devel kernel-PAE kernel-PAE-debug
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: cdc. Please verify its path and try again
---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 returned 1
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.1/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:289:in `invalid!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.1/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:276:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:56:in `shell_out!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:719:in `refresh'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:836:in `package_available?'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1104:in `block in load_current_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1103:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1103:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1103:in `load_current_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider.rb:127:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource.rb:585:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:648:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:648:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:687:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:269:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:270:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:258:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:258:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:224:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:212:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:408:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:398:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:398:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:388:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:54:in `load'
```

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue already fixed with 12.1.1 check this https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3030. It's seems like permission issue.

Comment: Hi Ammy,Thanks for your response. I am running this cookbook as root user. I don't think this issue is related to permission and chef-client version is 12.5.1.

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy?